# How to make Opera display full zoomed-out thumbnails like it used to?

Tags: opera, thumbnails, speed-dial

Since a few versions ago, Opera has started displaying unscaled thumbnails in speed dial, which I find invariably useless, most sites only showing a bit of logo and a header. I would like to return to the old style, where thumbnails were scaled (zoomed out, in most cases) to fit the full minimum width of the website inside the thumbnail. Some have suggested this [trick](http://www.favbrowser.com/opera-show-full-site-thumbnails-old-speed-dial/), however it results in a thumbnail that does not get refreshed periodically.

The behavior seems to change arbitrarily between the old and the new way for some thumbnails every now and again. I would very much like to restore the old functionality without manually creating thumbnails for each and every site, since I use quite a few thumbnails that are reloaded every n minutes to get updates at a glance.

[image: Desired behavior (left) and undesired behavior (right)]

*Desired behavior (left) and undesired behavior (right)*

Comment: Are you sure that trick doesn't work for you? I've just confirmed it still works on 12.02 on Win7 and Ubuntu (set reload to, say, 30 minutes, _do a reload_, and set it back to never reload). Have you changed other settings? Try it on a plain new unmodified installation (you can have multiple ones side-by-side) and see if that works for you. If so, it's something you've customised; if not, it's something about your particular system or the site you're trying to put on speed dial, and you'll need to provide more details.

Comment: @aaamos you're right, it does appear to work, though it doesn't solve my problem - I need them to be reloaded regularly. I'll update the question.

Comment: I'm almost afraid to point out the obvious, but you _have_ tried _not_ setting the reload option back to "never reload", right...? You do realise that that is just in the instructions so that people who _don't_ want tabs constantly reloading can get the thumbnail images? If you want them to reload, just leave the setting on "reload every <frequency>".

Comment: @aaamos yes, I have.

Comment: Then, as I said above, you'll have to provide more details. I can put the stackoverflow main page on my speed dial, set it to a custom "reload every 1 minute", and... it reloads every minute, as expected. If you want more than a "it's not me, it's you" answer, try it with a plain vanilla installation to rule out that your problem is due to one of your customisations. Then, if it is, apply your customisations one at a time to see which breaks it; if not, post back with a specific site example and the settings you're using that don't work.

Comment: @aaamos the problem isn't that they don't reload, but that they seemingly randomly switch between modes 1 and 2 as seen in the screenshot. I'll try with a fresh installation.

Comment: @aaamos looks like Ghostery was the culprit. Lesson of the day: just because something shouldn't affect something doesn't mean it won't. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to hear you found it... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug may be caused by using Ghostery 0.9.6, as documented [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/ghostery/topics/0_9_6_interferes_with_creation_of_opera_speeddial_miniatures). Ghostery 0.9.7, released November 6, 2012, has fixed this issue.